# Multiple RPMs for the same node

Tags: rpm, puppet

we have a project, which is deployed using puppet and RPM, it deploys a WAR file to tomcat and it works just fine.

The issue is that we're adding another war to the project and we are not really certain (yet) whether they would be 2 separate projects or one after all. In addition, we'd like to keep an option to release only one war.

My original idea was to create 2 RPMs and deploy both on the same node, and if we decide to separate them we'll just change the node for one of them, but I was told I cannot put 2 RPMs on the same node (though I can't find anything about this restriction on the web).

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it true that I cannot deploy 2 RPMs on the same node?
2. Is there some way to do this other then create 3 puppet scripts projects? (1 for each and 1 for the combination) Which will create a lot of duplication and also trouble when we start working on the 3rd war?

**Right now,  we'd like both wars to be deployed on the same node**

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand why you can't put two RPMs on the same server. The RPMs will be named different things, and I assume the WAR files do different things as well? I'm not a Java expert but I've never heard of such a problem occurring, now if you were trying to use similarly named WAR file with internal changes I could see there being a problem. Regarding Puppet it really depends how you do it. You could make one single parameterized class where you'd pass in the status of each package depending on either the hostname, or a value you set when you include it. Or you could go with 3 classes.

Comment: This is what I was told, I can't seem to find any reference to it and our expert is OOO

Comment: I agree that as long as your RPMs have different names, there is no reason you can't deploy more than one RPM to the same node.  They do need to have unique names, though.

Comment: Do you have a test environment you can try to deploy this into before you take it to the prod environment? If so I'd say build the RPMs and then just see how the WAR files deploy.